# Convert redundant trait ADT to abstract class with generic value?

Tags: scala

I have code that wraps a few expected types for fields that I am using. That I would like to convert to an abstract class.

```
  sealed trait SJValue
  case class SJDouble(value: Double) extends SJValue {
    def toValue: Double = value
  }
  case class SJInt(value: Int) extends SJValue {
    def toValue: Int = value
  }
  case class SJString(value: String) extends SJValue {
    def toValue: Double = value
  }
  case class SJBoolean(value: Boolean) extends SJValue {
    def toValue: Boolean = value
  }
```

I feel like I could do something like this to get rid of the duplicate `toValue` classes but I can't quite figure out how:

`abstract class SJValue[T <: ???](value: T) { toValue : T }`
As you can see I'm kind of treating this like an or type for Int, String, Double, and Boolean, So I'm not sure what the actual type constraint would be because Any is too broad.

Comment: why does T need a type constraint if you make it sealed?

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like

```
sealed trait SJValue[A] {
  def toValue: A
}
case class SJDouble(
  override val toValue: Double
) extends SJValue[Double]
case class SJInt(
  override val toValue: Int
) extends SJValue[Int]
case class SJString(
  override val toValue: String
) extends SJValue[String]
case class SJBoolean(
  override val toValue: Boolean
) extends SJValue[Boolean]
```

this?

Since `SJValue` is `sealed` it cannot be of any type other than one of these hardcoded 4.

```
// [A] can only be Double | Int | String | Boolean
// because you cannot create SJValue with a different A
def extract[A](sjvalue: SJValue[A]) = sjvalue.toValue
```

```
sjvalue match {
  case JSDouble(value)  => // Scala knows value is Double
  case JSInt(value)     => // Scala knows value is Int
  case JSString(value)  => // Scala knows value is String
  case JSBoolean(value) => // Scala knows value is Boolean
}
```

If you want to have `abstract class` instead of `trait` it can still be `sealed`

```
sealed abstract class SJValue[A](
  val toValue: A
)
case class SJDouble(
  toDouble: Double
) extends JSValue[Double](toValue)
...
```

If you wanted to totally get rid of the duplication though, I think you'd have to go to Scala 3 which should allow you to write:

```
case class JSValue[A <: Int | Double | String | Boolean](
  toValue: A
)
```

but this might have its own issues. To achieve the same in Scala 2 you'd have to [try some fragile black magic](https://milessabin.com/blog/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/) based on implicit evidence.